# how to select entries from database for particular fields entered in php

Tags: php, oracle10g, oracle11g

I have php page thats taking values for startdate, enddate, hotelname, city, price and type from the user.
Now i need to check my database for only the values that are entered by the user. Is that possible? For any entry that is left blank, the corresponding condition is not applied (e.g., if city is left blank, all cities are considered).
Like if the user enters only the hotelname then i need to select * from hotel where hname = hotelname.

If i go on checking for all the possible set of conditions then it will be to long like 63 combinations are possible!! so is there any way out? please help! Thanks.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you are building some kind of search form that allows the user to search for entries in your database using different search criteria? And you don't know how to make the database query that incorporates all not-empty fields from the form?

Comment: What have you tried? What is your current code? Where **exactly** are you stuck?

Comment: yes. the user can search with any number of search criteria, to be more clear the user ca search with one search criteria or all 6 of them! How can i check how many search criteria has user entered and search through my database for them?

Comment: i have tried considering only 3 search criteria but then there are 7 possible combinations of if(!hotelname)if(!city)if(!type)....else...else...else... so to check for 6 search criteria it will be too long and illogical.. so is there any better solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

You should write a method that loops through the input vars and looks for valid column names instead of handling each input individually. Then make sure you are using prepared statements in your SQL (mysqli, PDO).

To check for specific input vars, you should perform an

`if (isset($_POST['var']) && !empty($_POST['var']))`

If each field needs special attention or separate database tables, then you will most likely need to handle each field individually.

It ultimately depends on your needs. But in my experience there is always a way to do it pro-grammatically.

Answer (score 0):

When you build your query in your code, only include the items that have values in them.

You ARE building your query dynamically aren't you?

Comment: no the query is static only the values is entered dynamically!

Comment: Well there is your problem. No one in their right mind would do this with anything other than a dynamically built query. Why are you using a static one?

Comment: im sorry i dont know how to build dynamic query as im new to php. can u please guide me from where can i learn building dynamic query? or if u can post any sample dynamic query?

Comment: What are you using to submit your query? Are you using PDO or just submitting raw SQL?

Comment: Are you using prepared queries or just submitting raw SQL?